# export_fig, GUI and gcf - Matlab 2015b

Tags: matlab

I have found the code below in the net (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/322200)

```
[fileName filePath] = uiputfile('*.jpg','Save As');
if filePath == 0
    return;
end
saveFileAs = ([filePath fileName]);
addpath('export_fig')
export_fig(handles.axes1,saveFileAs);
set(gcf, 'Color', 'w');
```

I use it in Matlab GUI (via button). My questions are do I need the set(gcf, 'Color', 'w') line as I removed it and all looks ok? what does it do?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation for [`set`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html), [`gcf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gcf.html), and [`figure` properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_color) would be *great* places to find this information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set(gcf, 'Color', 'w');
```

... sets the background of the current figure white

For further informations [see here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html) and [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/set.html).

You don't need this line of code for the exported figure because the image gets exported beforehand.

Comment: White is not actually the default background color. The default color depends upon `get(0, 'DefaultFigureColor')`

Comment: @Suever Thx for your comment. I confused the figure window background color and the background of the actual figure (say if you draw something with `plot`)

Comment: Well that is *also* not necessarily white. That depends on `get(0, 'defaultaxescolor')` and can be changed using `set(0, 'defaultaxescolor', color)`. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: But I think white is the default value for `get(0, 'defaultaxescolor')`

Comment: On your machine with your current configuration, yes.

Comment: @Suever my default is `[1 0 1]`, please send help

Comment: @excaza Like Suever already said: _and can be changed using `set(0, 'defaulltaxescolor', color)`_ - Possible values for `color` can be found [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colorspec.html?requestedDomain=de.mathworks.com)